# Batch file installing executable only gives SYSTEM permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy, batch-file

So, I have a couple of batch files that install some executables and they work, but when the executables setup shortcuts on the desktop only `SYSTEM` has access to them. Is there a way I can prevent that or make it so it adds `Domain Users` access or something like that. I realize that the batch files are ran under the `SYSTEM` context, but I'd like to find a way to clean up after them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "only `SYSTEM` has access to them". Define "access". Are the shortcuts getting put into the SYSTEM profile's desktop instead of the "Public" desktop? It might just be a matter of changing the batch file to reference the machine's "Public" desktop folder, since files created there will inherit that folder's ACL.

Answer (score 0):

You cold have the batch file change the permissions on the file to add the Domain Users group to the file by using the [ICACLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) command.